# Undefined Variable in __ construct

Tags: php, variables, undefined, construct

When i try to define a variable in __construct it still gives me an error of an undefined varbile. could you help?

```
    <?php



    class view {

public $model;


function    __construct($url,$root,$model,$common_model,$common_view,$alt_root,$it_selected,$hr_selected,$finance_selected) {

    $this->it_selected = $it_selected;
    $this->hr_selected = $hr_selected;
    $this->finance_selected = $finance_selected;
    $this->url = $url;
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->common_model = $common_model;
    $this->common_view = $common_view;
    $this->root = $root;
    $this->alt_root = $alt_root;


    $this->loader();


}
```

i still recieve it_selected, hr_selected & finance_selected are not defined.

Comment: You have to define them in your PHP class like you defined `$model`.

Comment: In other word under `public $model`, add `private $it_selected;` or public, do that for all the var u using in the construct

Comment: Please show us all the error messages, in their entirety.

Comment: Also, are you sure it does not have something to do with the variables that are passed *into* the constructor, when instantiating the class? For example, `new view($a, $b, $c, ...)`, are all the `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `...` variables defined?

Comment: Do you call the __construct with all 9 parameters? The closest I can come to your error is calling __construct() with only 6 parameters, which leads to 3 warnings and 3 notices.

Comment: these are the error codes i was getting before i changed the code.

    undefined variable: it_selected in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/view/the_helpdesk.php line 457 undefined variable: finance_selected in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/view/the_helpdesk.php line 457 undefined variable: hr_selected in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/view/the_helpdesk.php line 457

Comment: Can you show us the line 457 of the file `the_helpdesk.php`?

Comment: They are all on the same line. It is probably when you instantiate the class. Please show us line 457.

Comment: <option value="finance"'.$finance_selected.'>Finance</option><option value="hr"'.$hr_selected.'>HR</option><option value="it"'.$it_selected.'>IT</option>

Comment: @JamieSterling That is not the line that is causing this.

Comment: <fieldset><legend><b>Current View</b></legend><b>Helpdesk:</b> <select id="which_helpdesk" name="which_helpdesk" onchange="window.location.href=\''.$this->root.'the_helpdesk/switchhelpdesk/\'+this.value+\'#helpdesk\';"><option value="finance"'.$finance_selected.'>Finance</option><option value="hr"'.$hr_selected.'>HR</option><option value="it"'.$it_selected.'>IT</option></select>

Comment: this is the line that is for the error code.

Comment: @JamieSterling Okay... that did not help us much. Can you account for where `$it_selected`, `$hr_selected` and `$finance_selected` are defined? Also, it would help us a lot if you showed us *all the relevant code*. The snippets you have shown us are not enough for us to get the whole picture.

Comment: i cannot add the whole code into a page but here is the .php file

http://www.mediafire.com/view/4pa1edxtrtqkdk8/the_helpdesk.php